# JavaScript - number multi split

Tags: javascript

I have a number in JS like `2,5` or `2.5`

I want to use a multi split like

```
'2.5'.split(/,|./)
```

but it gives me the wrong output, why ?:

```
["", "", "", ""]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/,|./` is incorrect regex. It should be in a charatcer class `/[,.]/` or be escaped `/,|\./`

This works: `'2.5'.split(/[.,]/)`

Comment: @Bergi - Yes, only dot to be escaped. Corrected.

Answer (score 3):

Escape the . regex metacharacter

```
'2.5'.split(/,|\./)
```

Comment: Whoops, got ahead of myself.